# Nuxt.js - external component does not work inside another component after npm generate

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

On the page I use my component that I import locally.

Inside that component I use an external one (vue-carousel) but since it's client only, I've built a plugin that imports the vue-carousel and registers its components globally.

It works on **`npm run dev`** but if I run **`npm run generate`** it stops working and in the inspector I see the  tags instead of the component itself. I use a local IIS setup.

Demo repo: https://github.com/MrZordex/inner-component-problem

Any ideas how that could happen?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
plugins: [
  {src: '@/plugins/vue-carousel.client.js', mode: 'client'}
  // {src: '@/plugins/vue-carousel.client.js', ssr: false}  // or
]
```

Some plugins might work only in the browser because they lack SSR support. In these situations you can use the `mode: client` option in `plugins` to add the plugin only on the client-side.

**Note**: Since Nuxt.js 2.4, `mode` has been introduced as option of plugins to specify plugin type, possible value are: `client` or `server`. `ssr: false` will be adapted to `mode: 'client'` and deprecated in next major release.

Comment: .client.js does exactly the same (and this doesn't help).

Comment: You can see this [issue](https://github.com/SSENSE/vue-carousel/issues/31) @Zordex

Comment: Thanks, wrapping with <client-only> did the work. The only downside is I can't see the content of the slides in the page source but at least it works now